# StreamReader returning ("")

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading from the `MemoryStream` and then I'm converting back to a string, but the value is (""). I read the Microsoft documentation abut the `StreamReader` but didn't understand exactly what I need to do to avoid this.

Heres my code:

```
byte[] bytee = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytee );

MemoryStream original =  Encryption.SymmetricEncrypt(stream);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(original);
reader.ReadToEnd();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
user = text;
```

Comment: Hi, what's your goal?

Comment: Shouldn't be `reader.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` instead of `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`?

Comment: @Stefan I want to encrypt a value (the encryption part works well) but in order to call the Encrypt() method I need to convert this value which is string to a MemoryStream value, which I believe this code does. My final goal is to get the encrypted value and convert it back to string so that I can save it in the database.

Comment: @dcg It doesn't work like that, it gives an error

Comment: Seems to work without Encryption.SymmetricEncrypt(stream) - could the encryption be the issue - could you be encrypting the test to something that appears empty, or to an empty string/stream?

Comment: What is Encryption.SymmetricEncrypt(stream) here? Most encryption algorithms work as binary, so the output is unlikely to be text, yet SteamReader is text-centric. The most obvious glitch here is the extra ReadToEnd which doesn't do what you think it does, but: I'm concerned that you approach is doomed anyways. So: what is Encryption.SymmetricEncrypt(stream)?

Comment: The encryption isn't the issue because the value original has data in it (length = 16 etc..)

Comment: @MarcGravell Encryption.SymmetricEncrypt(stream) is a method inside a class called Encryption which does Symmetric encryption :)

Comment: Ultimately, the double read here is pointless and harmful; Gauravsa has already mentioned the fix to that bit, but: I'm worried that even with this your code isn't doing what you think it is, because of what looks like a doomed approach

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks I appreciate, the SymmetricEncrypt is of type MemeroyStream which generates a secret key + IV and the by using CryptoStream I'm passing the keys to store the encrypted data. Also from a length of 4 passing through the encrypt method it becuase of length 16

Comment: @User89 OK, so: you've run some symmetric encryption algo, and put the results into a memory stream - are there any reasons we should expect that data to be text? And: what is the position of the returned memory stream? If you've used Write, it'll be at the end, so you need to reset it to 0 **before** you create the reader. If you've used the constructor, it'll be at the start, so: shouldn't be needed

Comment: @MarcGravell The result will be a mix of letters and numbers.. but since I'm calling from a string it should be safe? And yes I used CryptoStreamMode.Write as a result the position is always at the end(if length = 16, position = 16)

Comment: @MarcGravell I figured it out now and it's solved. Thanks for the information you have given, it has helped a lot!

Comment: @user89 are you using a special crypto API with restricted output range to achieve that? Because most crypto APIs **will not** output a mix of letters and numbers *at all* - it'll be bytes in no particular encoding or meaning. As for the other bit: then set the position to 0 **before** creating the reader, and use the code in gauravsa's answer. But: unless you confirm that the *cipher* data conveyed is actually text, you're going to get corrupt output that cannot ever be decrypted (because it is invalid and incorrect)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I read your advice and I set the position to 0 before the reader. The output was bytes in no particular encoding or meaning as you wrote. Sorry for the misinformation

Comment: @User89 then a text-reader is useless to you; alternative option provided as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- the relative positions of the stream and reader
- whether the contents are actually text

The latter is a bigger issue; most crypto APIs **are not** text based, so using a text-reader is simply wrong. Since this is a MemoryStream, we have another option that solves both issues in one go:

- access the raw buffer, and base-64 encode the binary payload

Code:

```cs
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(
    original.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)original.Length);
```

To reverse this, use `Convert.FromBase64String`, and use the `byte[]` in the constructor of a new `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

And remove the

```
reader.ReadToEnd();
 stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: I need to encrypt the value before getting the value back

Comment: I want to store the encrypted value in the database, but it's giving me a value of (""). I read that this is because the current position is at the end of the stream

Comment: Remove the two lines reader.ReadToEnd(); and stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: I've done that but its giving me the same value of ("")

Comment: Instead of encoding.utf8, can you try Encoding.ASCII

Comment: I've done that aswell haha. The thing is that the StreamReader is returning the empty string because of its position

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's returning an empty string because of it's position? How can you validate that? What's the value of "user"?

Comment: I'm sure because as I read the documentation of Microsoft it says "If the current position is at the end of the stream, returns an empty string ("")", also if I hover over the StreamReader isLastElement is true. The value of the user is by user input and user is truning null after the code goes int the StremReader line

Comment: Calling ReadToEnd twice has nothing whatsoever to do with encrypting the value before you read it, especially since this is a MemoryStream (so: nothing interesting is happening when you read it)

Comment: @MarcGravell I've called ReadToEnd twice to reset the StreamReader's position

Comment: @User89 that won't work, though; this is a memory stream: the stream's contents aren't going to change between reads, and: resetting the stream' position doesn't automatically update the reader - the reader can have its own buffer and state, and if the reader thinks it is ended: it is allowed to short-cut. Again: this will not and cannot do anything interesting, so: don't do that. If you want to read the contents, the code in this answer shows how to do that, **assuming that they are text** (in the right encoding); personally, I doubt that they are text.